# Permission denied when starting hadoop

Tags: hadoop, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I'm trying to run Hadoop 2.7.1 on Centos 7.

When I'm invoking script start-dfs.sh, I'm getting following error:

```
    localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/bin/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-   datanode-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost: nice: /usr/bin/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/bin/hdfs: Permission denied
```

environment variables are set as:

```
HADOOP_HOME=/usr/bin/hadoop
HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/usr/bin/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs
HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=/usr/bin/hadoop/lib/native
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/bin/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*
```

core-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

hdfs-site.xml has not been set up.
I'm struggling for the last few days, so I would also be helpful for any link to a site with detailed explanation of each option.

tnx

additional:

```
/usr/bin/hadoop/logs:hadoop]start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
59: starting hadoop-daemons.sh
hadoop@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/bin/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost: nice: /usr/bin/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/bin/hdfs: No such file or directory
73: starting hadoop-daemons.sh
hadoop@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/bin/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost: nice: /usr/bin/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/bin/hdfs: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
The authenticity of host '0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 14:f8:1e:51:32:e9:25:94:45:99:5d:a6:01:89:a2:7d.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
0.0.0.0: Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: check for permissions on /usr/bin/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/bin/hdfs

Comment: group and owner are correctly set up (for 'hadoop' user). Also, I checked all other directories.

Comment: With other directories, you mean @bongo, the entire tree on /usr/bin/hadoop?

Comment: Please provide error reported in logfile -  /usr/bin/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-localhost.localdomain.log while running start-dfs.sh?

Comment: http://codesfusion.blogspot.in/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: nice: /usr/bin/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/bin/hdfs: Permission denied
ulimit -a for user hadoop
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15036
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024

Comment: I have changed my initial post to give you full message that I got